# Games do not download on Steam

Tags: steam

I have just bought Civilization 5 online through Steam as they had a promotional weekend. They were quick enough to take my money but the game does not download and now they won't respond to my mails to the support desk.

Any ideas? Do I simply call my CC provider and block this?

Does anybody who went through a similar experience have a solution?

Comment: Is this problem exclusive to Civilization 5 or can you not download any other games on Steam? It might be some temporary server problems on their end.

Comment: Have you tried switching the content server to download from?

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you mean by "the game does not download"? Does it appear in your games list?

Comment: Relevant story: when I got Portal, during that one Portal for free week, the game was added immediately to my library but the servers were too overloaded to let me get it right away. I had to wait one day for the load to reduce, then I could get my copy too.

Comment: Are you running another program through steam at the moment?  If steam detects you running a game, it will automatically pause all downloads and resume them when you stop.  This isn't limited to games, but any applications that you have managed through Steam.

Comment: @badp, same problem with alien swarm

Comment: Are you on a Mac, by any chance?

Comment: "just bought" - "won't respond" - how long have you been waiting?

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes deleting the ClientRegistry blob and having Steam rebuild its cache of games helps.

From the [ClientRegistry.blob answer on Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7241-EYON-2343):

Windows XP/Vista/7

- Completely exit from the Steam client.
- Go to `C:\Program Files\Steam` (or the Steam directory that was specified during installation).
- Locate `ClientRegistry.blob` and rename this file to `ClientRegistryOld.blob`
- Restart Steam to allow the file to be recreated.
- Test the issue once more.

Mac OS X

- Completely exit from the Steam client.
- Go to `/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Steam`
- Locate `ClientRegistry.blob` and rename this file to `ClientRegistryOld.blob`
- Restart Steam to allow the file to be recreated.
- Test the issue once more.

Comment: I have had issues with steam logging on for a month. Steam support has sent me several kb articles that have been useless. This fix fr Mac got me back up instantly! Than you.

Comment: Well, so far, this solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 7):

I've bought 10+ games on steam and they've all downloaded without problem.

- Have you read the FAQ? There might be something there about it or what to do
- Perhaps your firewall is too strict
- Perhaps your ISP doesn't allow it
- Perhaps your CC is from another country then you're trying to download too
- How long have you given them to respond? 1 day 2 days? 1 week?

I've personally found Steam to be fairly efficient, and if something isn't working they do what they can to fix it. Also why block on your CC? WHy not just ask them for a refund? If you block on your CC you are just giving yourself a bad record with steam, if you ask for a refund because x doesn't download IMO that's a lot better and makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Did the download somehow pause itself?  Go to Library -> Downloads and make sure.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I would relax a bit.  They probably did not respond due to the fact that it was a holiday weekend in the United States.  They will most likely respond today or tomorrow, as I'm sure they have quite a backlog of support requests.

Second, try [changing your download region](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5483-YUFN-0521).  Generally when I have a download that is "suspended" its just that the content delivery server is full.  Switching to one nearby that [has less traffic](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/content/) generally fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem - **all** games refused to download.

Opting **out** of the Steam beta *(view --> settings --> account --> beta participation)* fixed the problem for me.